# How can I access an entities score information and or existence from the luis.ai RecognizerAsync method which returns the RecognizerResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, botframework, azure-language-understanding

The sample bot built through azure has a basis from this documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

I am trying to refactor parts of the functionality of the dialog and I need access to parts of the json that I assume should come back from the luis call.  However, when I try to access from $instance I get an error that I cannot access child elements of the response.

Here is an exmaple of the json:

```
+       Entities    {{
  "$instance": {
    "To": [
      {
        "startIndex": 10,
        "endIndex": 15,
        "text": "paris",
        "type": "To",
        "score": 0.987954
      }
    ]
  },
  "To": [
    {
      "$instance": {
        "Airport": [
          {
            "startIndex": 10,
            "endIndex": 15,
            "text": "paris",
            "type": "Airport"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Airport": [
        [
          "Paris"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}}  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
```

Here is the code accessing the json:

```cs
bookingDetails.Origin = recognizerResult.Entities["From"]?.FirstOrDefault()?["Airport"]?.FirstOrDefault()?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
```

I understand how this accesses the Entity from luis.ai call but how can I access the other parts of the json response?

As well, is there a way to access whether or not an entity came back for the intent in general such as a bool valued response?

Lastly, accessing the json in general via the above method seems not ideal. Is there a more formatted way to access what would be the json return and with the new asp.net core 2+ is there a way to do it without using newtonsoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that accessing the JSON via the above method is not ideal. What I would do it use a tool such as [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) to create a class from JSON, or at least the [basis of a class that you can tweak](https://app.quicktype.io?share=ZGa0Nc7JPICpdo8kRI71). You can then use the NewtonSoft JSON library (or an alternative JSON library since you don't want to use NewtonSoft) to [Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) the JSON into an object and access the Score property of the object.

Alternatively, as shown in the guide that you linked you can obtain the score from the `GetTopScoringIntent` method call.

Regarding checking if any entities were returned you can plug the JSON shown on the [LUIS API reference](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78) page under the 200 response into the quicktype tool I linked above to create a class then check against the `Entities` collection to see if it has any items - you could use LINQs `.Any()` method for this.

---

**Edit**

The OP ended up using [LUISGen](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/LUISGen/src/npm/readme.md) to output a class to deserialize the response from the LUIS API.

1. Go to the LUIS portal.
2. Navigate into the relevant LUIS app.
3. Go the the Manage tab.
4. On the left, select the Versions item.
5. Check the box next to the version you want to export.
6. From the dropdown, select Export as JSON.
7. Save the JSON into the root directory of your project.
8. Open a command prompt in the root directory of your project.
9. Run the following commands:

```
dotnet tool install -g LUISGen

LUISGen <exported-luis-app>.json -cs ClassToGenerate -o
```

10. Add the generated file to your project in Visual Studio.

    - Right click on the project > Add existing item
11. Using the generated class in code:

```
var result = recognizer.Recognize<ClassToGenerate>("<user-input-text>", CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: you're now the second person that suggested such a thing.  I am newer to c# and .net so if you could spell it out a little more that would be appreciated.  when you say create a class from JSON... I am assuming you're talking about the recognizer json or the recognizer.Entity json?  I can get the later easier than the former.  Again, if you could give a complete answer example that would help a lot.

Comment: What about using [LUISGen](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/LUISGen/src/npm/readme.md) in addition to above answer.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew add [this class](https://pastebin.com/RfESUH1G) to your project, then update `var recognizerResult = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);` to `var recognizerResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(turnContext, cancellationToken);` and you will now be able to access the JSON properties through a concrete implementation i.e. recognizerResult.Entities or recognizerResult.Intents.

Comment: @MattStannett I am unsure what and how you are using cognitiveModels.DispatchService.  What is that and where did it come from

Comment: @MattStannett I think you just included dispatch organization from what I see.  However, while intents come through nicely... Entities aren't coming through at all.  I am going to try the luis generator

Comment: @Mick have you used the generator?  If so, does it work well with entities will I be able to call for a specific one like "To" in the example above?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew sorry I transposed cognitiveModels.DispatchService from the Virtual Assistant Template which you aren't using. Take a look a my paste [here](https://pastebin.com/gR3CDm6s). It contains a new class for you to add, as well as how to use that class inside `ExecuteLuisQuery` method in your `LuisHelper.cs` file.

Comment: @MattStannett a little confused on how do you now add this to the recognizerResult for the luis integration i.e.   var recognizerResult = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(turnContext, cancellationToken);

Comment: @MattStannett thank you for your time. I appreciate the help. Yes the luisgen is just to good. However, I am still not sure what I would gain by this vs the existing api implementation.  Would you be able to add anything to that question?

Comment: Did you want to know what you gain from using LUISGen to create a model that can then be used to deserialise the recogniser result vs just using the anonymous tuple that is returned by default?