# How to deserialize luis entity in IRecognizerConvert

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

In Luis, I created a simple pattern with a simple entity like this:

```
list bots {Name}
```

where "Name" is my entity that I would like to get in C#.  The pattern and intent works fine and I am getting that correctly.

I follow the official example and built a IRecognizerConvert class so I can deserialize the result.  It deserialize the intent just fine but fail to deserialize the entity.

In the _Entities sub-class, I only have the "Name" variable that I am trying to deserialize and nothing else.  I don't have any other partial class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis;

namespace EmptyBot1.Models
{
    public class ChatbotIntent : IRecognizerConvert
    {
        public string Text;
        public string AlteredText;
        public enum Intent
        {
            CreateBot,
            ListBots,
            ListAllBots,
            RunBot,
            Cancel,
            Greet,
            None
        };
        public Dictionary<Intent, IntentScore> Intents;

        public class _Entities
        {
            public string Name;
        }
        public _Entities Entities;

        [JsonExtensionData(ReadData = true, WriteData = true)]
        public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

        public void Convert(dynamic result)
        {
            var _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatbotIntent>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
            Text = _result.Text;
            AlteredText = _result.AlteredText;
            Intents = _result.Intents;
            Entities = _result.Entities;
            Properties = _result.Properties;
        }

        public (Intent intent, double score) TopIntent()
        {
            Intent maxIntent = Intent.None;
            var max = 0.0;
            foreach (var entry in Intents)
            {
                if (entry.Value.Score > max)
                {
                    maxIntent = entry.Key;
                    max = entry.Value.Score.Value;
                }
            }
            return (maxIntent, max);
        }
    }
}
```

In the previous snippet, the important part is the _Entities class which define how the entities look from coming back from Luis.  Since I only have 1 simple string entity "Name", I thought this is sufficient.

```
        public class _Entities
        {
            public string Name;
        }
```

However when I run it and I give it an utterance like:

```
"list bots mybots"
```

Luis would correctly assign Name="mybots" and get the correct intent, but it crash on the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject line saying the json format is incorrect.  I assume this is complaining about the class I made?  And not the actual JSON result from luis?

What do I need to add to the _Entities class so the luis entity can be successfully deserialzied?

Comment: Have you tried using [LUISGen](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/LUISGen) instead of creating the class by yourself? It's a command tool from the Microsoft team for exactly this - generating the IRecognizerConvert instance. At the very least, it might help you see what parts it generates differently.

Comment: I haven't, I will definitely try it!  Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Glad to help, let me know if you run into any trouble with it

Comment: As Hilton specified above, you can make use of [LUISGen](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/LUISGen/src/npm/readme.md) comand line tool for generating strongle typed class for the intents and entities defined in the LUIS model. Also , you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372143/how-can-i-access-an-entities-score-information-and-or-existence-from-the-luis-ai) SO issue which is similar to yours.

Comment: Yup worked out great!  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I'm facing the same situation now so I want to contribute with the step-by-step that worked for me.
As @ranusharao and Bill said, you need to download [LUISGen from GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/LUISGen).
Start a CMD, go to your solution's directory

```
cd C:\MySolutionFolder
```

and run

```
luis init
```

if you haven't done yet.
It will ask you for your App ID and information that you get in luis.ai.
After that, go to luis.ai / Manage / Versions, click on your current version and click Export as Json.
[image]
Place your JSON file in your solution's folder.
Once you have done that, run the following command in your console:

```
LUISGen C:\MyJSONPath\MyBot.json -cs MyClassName -o C:\MySolutionFolder
```

That -cs stands for C#, but if you are usign Typescript then change it for "-ts".
So there you have it, you can access your class with something like:

```
var result = await _luisRecognizerService._recognizer.RecognizeAsync<MyClassName>(turnContext, cancellationToken);
Console.WriteLine(result.Entities.Producto);
```

_luisRecognizerService is my instance of LuisRecognizer (dependency injection)

Comment: I marked your answer as correct since it have more details than mine.

Comment: I was simply trying to get a string value from the entities returned by LUIS. I have been stuck at this for a day. You post helped me a lot. Even though I'm not using the generated class. It did show me what I was doing wrong (the simple entity wasn't an array). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @ranusharao, using LUISGen tool, a class will automatically be generated that works with the bot framework.